# Calculate number of partitions where partitions have certain size

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, set-partition

Suppose we have some set $S = \{1,...,N\}$ and partition this set into subsets $S_i \in S$ such that $S_i \cap S_j = \emptyset$ if $i\neq j$. How many different partitions can make such that the biggest subsize has atleast cardinalty $|S| = k$.

**Example**
Let $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$ then there us ${4 \choose 4} = 1$ way to partition when $k=4$. There are ${4\choose 3} =4$ ways to partition when $k=3$. However there are ${4 \choose 2} + 3 = 9$ ways to partition when $k = 2$. The extra three comes from the partitions $(\{1,2\}, \{3,4\})$, $(\{1,3\}, \{2,4\})$, $(\{1,4\}, \{2,3\})$.

Is there a general way to calculate the number of partitions?

Comment: Calculating number of partitions is generally very messy.  Yes, we can write or rewrite expressions for this, but they won't be terribly useful to the average person.  Here, letting $p_k(n)$ be the number of partitions of $[n]$ such that the largest part has size exactly $k$, we have the number of partitions you are looking for will be $\sum\limits_{i=k}^N p_i(N)$.  Each term here is able to be calculated using a recurrence relation $p_k(n)=p_k(n-k)+p_{k-1}(n-1)$, but that can take considerable effort and it is not really able to be simplified before being given specific values for $k$ and $N$

Comment: @JMoravitz This question is about partitions of a labeled set, while your comment is about integer partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused as to what you are asking. You say you want to count the partitions where the largest part has size *at least* $k$. However, in the case where $N=4$ and $k=3$, you are only counting the four partitions that look like $(\{a,b,c\},\{d\})$. I think there should be five partitions in this case, since $(\{1,2,3,4\})$ also has largest part whose size is at least $3$.

Let

- $g(n,k)=$ the number of partitions of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ whose largest part has **at least** $k$ elements
- $e(n,k)=$ the number of partitions of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ whose largest part has **exactly** $k$ elements
- $\ell(n,k)=$ the number of partitions of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ whose largest part has **at most** $k$ elements

Basically, you start out asking for $g(n,k)$, but your examples are all computing $e(n,k)$.

I will show you how to compute all three of these functions. Let us start with $\ell(n,k)$. Using the theory of exponential generating functions, you can show
$$
\ell(n,k)=[x^n]\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{x^i}{i!}\right)
$$
The notation $[x^n]f(x)$ means "the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series $f(x)$." This can be computed using any computer algebra system, like Mathematica or Maple. We can also give a recursive equation for $\ell(n,k)$, which allows you to compute $\ell(n,k)$ using dynamic programming and the help of a computer.
$$
\ell(n+1,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom {n}i \ell(n-i,k)
$$
Now, we can leverage this to compute $g(n,k)$. We have that
$$
g(n,k)+\ell(n,k-1)=\text{total number of partitions} =B_n,
$$
where $B_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ Bell number. You can compute the Bell numbers using the exponential generating function equation $$B_n=[x^n]\exp(\exp (x)-1),$$ or the recursive equation
$$
B_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni B_i.
$$
Finally, we use either $\ell(n,k)$ or $g(n,k)$ to compute $e(n,k)$:
$$
e(n,k)=\ell(n,k)-\ell(n,k-1)=g(n,k)-g(n,k+1).
$$